# How to solve Databinding utils not found issue in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I am currently trying to learn android development and I am following the tutroials by codeLabs.

Here is my code

```
package com.example.android.aboutme

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.android.aboutme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding


  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)
    
    }
}
```

No matter what happens DataBindingUtils is always red and I cant import it

Here is a copy of my gradle build

```
buildFeatures{
    viewBinding = true
    dataBinding = true
}
```

Here is xml file too

```
<Layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

 <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@string/done"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
    <LinearLayout/>
 <Layout/>
```

And I am currently using android studio 4.0

I recieved the following error

```
 ActivityMainBinding! is not a subtype of ViewDataBinding!
```

Comment: Restart and Invalidate the cache

Comment: doesnot work. Any other suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done_button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Your XML has few errors.

Please copypaste this code into your layout xml and see if it will work. Please also try cleaning and Rebuilding and also `Invalidate Caches /Restart`  if it give you issues.

This is a test code if it works you can include things like fonts and strings which I have left out.

Comment: Interesting this actually work so the problem because of context attribute ?

Comment: Not really the context attribute, I think the problem was being caused by missing attributes for the LinearLayout and the _<LinearLayout>_ and _<Layout>_ Tags closing. Always close the LinearLayout Tag like this  `</LinearLayout>` but not like this `<LinearLayout/>`. The Layout tag should be closed like this `</layout>` but you closed it this way ` <Layout/>`

Answer (score 0):

```
try with this

 binding = DataBindingUtils.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a minor error on the DataBindingUtil.

It should be **DatabindingUtil** and not DataBindingUtils.

Please try this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //it is not DataBindingUtilS it is DataBindingUtil
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

}
```

}

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I edited my code and it doesnot work. Now it says that  ActivityMainBinding! is not a subtype of ViewDataBinding!

Comment: Hi @Ahmed  have you wrapped your _activity_main_ with `<layout> </layout>` tag?

Comment: Yes i did wrap it

Comment: Then try cleaning the project under the `Build Menu` select `Clean project` followed by `Rebuild`

Comment: Under the `File` menu try `Invalidate Caches / Restart`